# jquery Delegate only works on resize

Tags: jquery, delegates

In my web app, the click event of link with title drama is fired when I resize my window otherwise the click event is not fired. That is when I open my app and click on drama link, the click event is not fired whereas after I resize my window, the click event is fired on clicking the link. The click event of link with title comedy is fired always.

The links are dynamic so I used below delegate function to attach the click event.

```
$(document).delegate('a', 'click', function() { ... })
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="page" style="width: 50%;">
        <ul class="pageContent">
            <li>        
                <a class="ui-link" title="comedy" href="javascript:;"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page" style="width: 50%;">
        <ul class="pageContent">
            <li>        
                <a class="ui-link" title="drama" href="javascript:;"></a>
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use on instead of delegate $(document).on('a', 'click',

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a', ...)`

Comment: even with on function, I am facing the same issue

Comment: Of course, they're equivalent. `on` is just the newer, preferred name,

Comment: Where do you have the call to `delegate`?

Comment: its called on div's live function

Comment: It should be in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It's almost never right to bind one handler inside the handler for some other event.

Comment: I tried to put it in $(document).ready() also. I faced the same issue.